# Queuing Requests(delayed job) on downloading large CSV size file as background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, delayed-job

This works fine in my Controller.

```
def export_list_sites_as_csv
    require "csv"
    csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["id","name", 'etc']
      @search.relation.not_archived.each do |site|
        csv << [site.id, site.name, site.etc]
      end
    end
    send_data csv_string,
              :type => 'text/csv',
              :filename => '_sites.csv',
              :disposition => 'attachment'

  end
```

`@search` variable depends on user filter, at extent which will put **lot of load on RAM**, UX isn't good. As other requests will be put on hold until the current request is served. Which is also making my system hang. So looking to run at background process, and letting user know once it's ready to download.

When I try to move to Model.

> I get an error undefined method `send_data' for #<\Class:0x9f8bed0>

I'm moving to Model because I have to call delayed job on it.

Dealing with CSV and Delayed Job for first time.

Edit: `ActionController::Streaming` is available only in Controller so other way around? more often or not, this isn't going anywhere.

As **D-Side** answer says, I will have to look for other ways.

**Edit2:** Following http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job I was able to do

```
class ExportCsv < Struct(:site_ids, :user_id)

def perform
    require "csv"
    sites = Site.where(id: site_ids)
    CSV.open("tmp/#{user_id}.csv", "w+") do |csv|
      csv <<  ["id","name", 'etc']
      sites.each do |site|
        csv << ....
      end
    end
  end


  def after(job)
    send_file(
      ....
      )
  end

end
```

How to use `ActionController::Streaming` inside a custom class `ExportCsv`, or `Model`

**Edit:**

Understanding about synchronization and how I dealt with the situation,

**Answer** : http://imnithin.github.io/csv_download_with_delayed_job.html

Comment: `send_data` it is method available only in `ActionController::Streaming`.

Comment: so is there a way around for it? or to call delayed job on this method.

Comment: i think, you can do like, call the csv generated part in model as you did, and call that method in controller after that put result variable with send_data in same controller.

Comment: @amtest smart soln, will try it out and write back.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. DelayedJob is for executing jobs **outside** request-response chain in order to not delay a response. There's a good chance that DelayedJob will be sending data into **nowhere**, more likely with an error. If you intend on generating a downloadable file, you should have DelayedJob make a model instance that knows the file it points to, and have the user download it later, when it's done. Otherwise, if you don't mind the generation delay, using DelayedJob is pointless.

Comment: @Nithin, I guess you don't get the idea of asynchronous jobs. They're separated and completely independent of controller. An asynchronous task will do its job in this case, but it will not send the data back to client. You can use either SSE or WebSockets to tell client its results are ready for download, notify him to come back later or just tell him to wait for an e-mail with download link. You can even cache some chunks of these CSV file content and then merge them up on demand to make this process faster. It depends of the context what would be best fit.

Comment: OP implemented the solution described here: https://www.railscarma.com/blog/technical-articles/delayed-job-gem-for-csv/

Answer (score 4):

**The thing you're trying to do defeats the purpose of DelayedJob.**

When a user makes a request, the server should make a response in order to fullfill it. The problem is, that some requests take quite a lot of time to complete, and the user has to hang on and wait until it's done. A classic case – massive email delivery, but there are others, as you've mentioned, like data suite generation. Whatever. It takes more time to complete than time you can afford for your user to wait.

Now here comes DelayedJob. It executes a certain action without a context of a query to respond. It doesn't need to hurry. But you can't just slap `send_data` for it: **there won't be any query for it to respond to**. Instead, it should write the results of the job done into some persistent storage.

You have a number of ways of pulling this off.

- You can have your user notified via email when the dataset is ready. You can even attach it to the email, but I would not recommend it: you can't rely on email providers' readiness to accept a large chunk of data. Make a link for downloading the dataset instead and send it.

  - DelayedJob will need to render the dataset, save it into the file, get the link and send it in an email to a user.
- Make a section (a company of model, controller and views) of your app that sounds like "Completed requests", might be a part of user's profile. The "launch" request should instruct the user to come back later and look into that list to get the result.

  - DelayedJob will have to make an entry in that list there after the request is fullfilled. How the dataset is stored is irrelevant, but you could combine it with a way above, save it into a file and display a link to it.